# Push text files between my phone and my laptop using native OS/apps, not third party installs?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, data-transfer, text

I like to keep track of information with simple text files, and I'd like to push them back and forth (or synchronize them) with native iOS and macOS software.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's an example; I go to the library and on my laptop find many library book call numbers (each on a different tab in a browser).

I glob them together, sort the call numbers in order with Python then paste back into a text file.

**Then I hold my phone up to the screen and photograph it!**

Then I can go to the stacks and check the books without carrying around my laptop.

If there was a printer in the library nearby, I'd print it. If lists like this were shorter, I'd just copy them down by hand.

**Question:** How can I easily, painlessly push text files back and forth between my phone and my laptop?

---

[image: screen shot of text file]

Answer (score 1):

[AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106):

> With AirDrop, you can wirelessly send documents, photos, videos,
> websites, map locations, and more to a nearby Mac, iPhone, iPad, or
> iPod touch.

You should be able to “share” the text file and select your iPhone under AirDrop.

---

Another option is to [Copy and paste between devices](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/copy-and-paste-between-devices-mchl70368996/mac):

> With Universal Clipboard, you can copy text, images, photos, and
> videos on one Apple device and then paste the content on another Apple
> device. For example, you can copy a recipe from your Mac and paste it
> into a note on your nearby iPhone.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used AirDrip because I'd heard of it in the context of unwanted/unwelcomed images being pushed by strangers at awkward moments. These are not part of the original question but they highlight why I'm hoping something besides this is also possible: Can I AirDrop through USB (i.e. not the air)? Is my phone open to other people pushing files when I'm using it myself? I like to keep all that wireless stuff turned off except when necessary and just use the USB.

Comment: You can turn AirDrop on and off in the control center when you need it. Worst case a stranger sends a request to send you something and you could reject it. I understand the hesitation but once you learn how to use it, it’s very useful.

Comment: Okay I'll look into it, thanks! Will hold off a while though to see if something is possible without radio waves :-)

Comment: If I AirDrop a `.txt` file from my laptop to my phone (as the question describes) where will it go on my phone? Will there be a folder showing it? What application will find, open and read the `.txt` file that gets AirDropped?

Comment: I’m guessing a note? I typically drop a note from my Mac to my phone.

Comment: I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶t̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ Oh I do now. Yikes that's not a text file. My python scrips generate `.txt` files and so do I, with TextEdit. I'm really looking for an answer that explains how to "Push text files between my phone and my laptop using native OS/apps..." Maybe the answer is "There isn't one, but if you start writing notes with a different app, then..."

Comment: Just tried it, it pulls up a bunch of different apps you can open it in. Including the Files app. Another option is to save it to iCloud and access the file in the Files app on your iPhone.

Comment: Okay I will experiment on this. I'm sitting with my phone and laptop connected by USB much of the time, going to a cloud in that situation seems... sub-ideal, but that's just me. *Thanks!*

Comment: Added another option, to avoid needing to turn on AirDrop.

Comment: fascinating! It looks like instead of AirDrop it requires both devices to be *signed in* to something (into Apple itself?), which means they both still have to have radios turned on (unless the laptop is plugged into ethernet) but it is an alternative to AirDrop as advertised. Thank you for your continued research!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I easily, painlessly push text files back and forth between my phone and my laptop?

#### Use the cloud...

This is what Cloud synchronization was designed for.  This will work with iCloud, OneDrive, Dropbox, et al.  Simply create a file and put it in the directory that gets synchronized with your chosen service and the file will be available on all of your devices, in real time.

Additionally, these services include Note taking apps and document processing apps:

- iCloud:  Notes and Pages
- OneDrive:  OneNote and Word
- Dropbox:  Content editing and collaboration tools.

All of these are free (OneDrive includes free web versions of OneNote, Word, Excel, etc. and 5GB of storage)  You're not limited to just text files, but if you wanted to share a text file, that can be done as well.  Additionally, you don't need to be on the same network.

For instance, you can be logged into a public library computer where you can cut and paste the call numbers into a text file.  Your phone, connected to the cellular network, can be  signed into your OneDrive or iCloud account and your documents/notes will sync up over it's cellular data connection.

The beauty of this type of solution is it's all cross platform and you can have any mix of desktop (Mac, Windows, FreeBSD/Linux) or phone (iPhone or Android) and it will work as described. If you happen you switch to a tablet, it too will have access to the document(s) in real time.

#### If your not connected to the Internet

Bluetooth File transfer would be your best best.  [Apple has an excellent document](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-files-mac-bluetooth-devices-mchle7fa9e15/mac) detailing this.  Again, this one is platform agnostic - meaning it's not limited to Apple desktops and devices - you can have a Mac computer and an Android phone/tablet or an iPhone/iPad with a Windows, macOS, or BSD/Linux computer.

On macOS, you can simply enable *Bluetooth Sharing* in System Preferences

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This requires both devices to be connected to the internet to be completed, right? Even if I have a USB wire from one to the other, the file must first travel somewhere else on Earth and then back again? This only works if *both devices* have access to the internet? If only my phone has 4G internet, I can hotspot my laptop, If only my laptop has WiFIe internet maybe I can reverse hotspot my laptops internet to my phone or something, but it seems so sub-optimal to require internet and sign-ins just to move a text file between two physically connected devices on my desk.

Comment: Internet connected devices are ubiquitous nowadays - everything is connected.  Even the library computers are connected so this is actually the easiest solution.  If you're not connected, the next easiest would be Bluetooth file transfer.

Comment: I think that's some people's bias but lots of people still expect our devices to be useful without having to also buy into and then hook into an internet connection all the time. I think we've had this (almost exact) same conversation elsewhere and probably don't need to repeat it. You are welcome to be dependent on the internet for everything, but saying we all must be is a bridge too far for me. I have a physical data wire between two devices that trust each other. It's simply sub-optimal (proxy for a stronger word) to have always to go to a data center somewhere else on the planet.

Comment: I think you're reading words which I didn't write.  I said it's [ubiquitous](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ubiquitous) not *you must be connected.*  It is more likely than not that you will find Internet connected devices making the cloud the most convenient solution.

Comment: "Internet connected devices are ubiquitous nowadays - everything is connected" No, *everything* is not connected and even for things that are, they aren't *always* connected. I'm frequently unconnected, usually by design, but sometimes I'm on a tiny Indonesian island than only runs a generator 4 hours a day and there's no wireless unless you buy a satellite connection. A wire between two devices that trust each other and I've paid dearly enough for already *should be sufficient*, I shouldn't need two internet connections that are up in order to transfer a bit of ASCII.

Comment: tropical islands aside, I'm going to try this Bluetooth solution. It needs radios, but at least no internet; this may be exactly what I want!