# What's the quickest way to push a screenshot from my macbook's display on to my iPhone (instead of photographing it)?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, screen-capture

I regularly take snapshots of my Macbook's screen with my iPhone to capture information I need handy, a list of library books to go hunting for, a map plus a bus schedule, etc.

My iPhone is plugged via USB into my laptop for hotspotting, it seems like there should be some way to just push the screenshot sitting on my desktop into my phone with a drag and drop, but I can't think of any.

Is it possible? If so, is it quick and easy?

There are some methods that are cumbersome in answers to [Push photo from MacBook to iPhone via USB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237910/143729) but I am hoping that with the latest software updates there might be a much faster way.

---

You might ask

> Why not just photograph it?

Yes this works pretty well but

1. I get pixel moire patterns at certain phone-screen distances
2. the photos are rotated and have perspective distortion because I am really bad at holding the phone in exactly the right place.
3. White becomes gray, and because of the screen's non-uniform illumination wrt illumination angle it's always bright in the middle and darker near the edges/corners.
4. I get reflections from the Sun or bright lights as there is no specific anti-glare layer on macbook screens.
5. I have to remember to move it to a special screenshot folder on my phone or it gets lost quickly as I take a ton of photos. Presumably pushing an image from my desktop should put it in a special folder.

These are not killer problems of course, but I'd really like an electronic rather than optical solution.

---

From [Push text files between my phone and my laptop using native OS/apps, not third party installs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/402828/143729)

[image: iPhone photograph of my macbooks screen]

Comment: I dump stuff into the Notes app - mac to phone or phone to mac - it just does .

Comment: @SolarMike I'll take a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(Tested on macOS Monterey and iOS 15.3) You can use Mac's built-in function (Cmd+Shift+4) to crop the screen for your screenshot, then when the small preview box appears on the bottom right of your Mac's screen, click on it.

A preview window of your screenshot will appear. You can either do quick mark-ups, simply save it onto your Desktop by pressing "Done", or, in this case for you, press the share button and select AirDrop, find your iPhone's name and select it.

This allows the screenshot to be transferred wirelessly onto your iPhone very quickly and when the screenshot is transferred, it will show up on your iPhone's Photos App and you can then decide where to move it to.

Comment: Believe it or not I have never used airdrop. It seems today is the day for me to finally learn how. *Thanks!*

Comment: Glad to know you learnt about using AirDrop from me! We all learn something new everyday. If you think this answer is helpful to you, please consider marking it as accepted answer as it helps me increases the number besides my profile picture :)

Answer (score 1):

I do the cmd shift 4 for screenshots I want to outline, then text to myself. I then can get them on my iPhone from the message and save to photos. The below works too as mentioned - airdrop them to the phone if you use that.

Comment: Interesting! How can I text myself from my Macbook? Can I do it from native OS or apps that come with it, or do I have to use a 3rd party app? Do I need another phone number or a registered account with some service?

Comment: open the native "messages" app. In settings you can actually configure it to sync those messages with the messages on your iPhone. However, IMO AirDrop is the much better option than texting yourself.

Comment: I do sync to the cloud my iMessages and with other devices so the messages are on all my devices that are signed in with the same apple id.  I also pin my message so its always on the top of the message list.  I do use air drop much as I dont like it always on - especially in the "everyone" mode.  Curious X_841 ---  why is airdrop much better?

Comment: @Stumped AirDrop is designed for quickly sending data between your Apple devices. It is the native and built-in way to do so and it can be done in any app that utilizes Apple's content sharing module (a small pop up showing different apps to share to like Messages, Reminders, Notes etc) and about you not liking to turn AirDrop on due to "everyone" mode, on a Mac and iPhone (or maybe all Apple devices), you can choose whether to open AirDrop to everyone or just you and your contacts. This will stop circumstances of random people on the streets AirDrop random photos to you from happening.

Comment: tks - all good points.  yep, I know the contacts mode was there. I was just saying that I dont leave it on, especially in the everyone mode.  for me messages does exactly what op was asking for and I dont have to go and turn something on I dont use thats all. just wondering why X_841 thought it much better.